# Strimzi Kafka external listeners Ingress error on VM

Tags: kubernetes, strimzi

I'm trying to deploy Kafka with Strimzi on a Kubernetes Cluster runnng on VM (VMWare Workstation 15 and Ubuntu 20.04 running on it), using kubeadm, kubelet, containerd, Calico, MetalLb.

I can create the ingress nginx controller service of type loadbalancer with IP from range that I have specified, but when i create the Kafka cluster and its external listeners of type ingress and try to associate the DNS it crashes with error:

**Exceeded timeout of 300000ms while waiting for Ingress resource my-cluster-kafka-bootstrap in namespace default to be addressable**

This is the whole stack trace (from Strimzi cluster operator logs)

```
2021-09-16 16:59:21 WARN  AbstractOperator:481 - Reconciliation #100(timer) Kafka(default/my-cluster): Failed to reconcile
io.strimzi.operator.common.operator.resource.TimeoutException: Exceeded timeout of 300000ms while waiting for Ingress resource my-cluster-kafka-bootstrap in namespace default to be addressable
    at io.strimzi.operator.common.Util$1.lambda$handle$1(Util.java:139) ~[io.strimzi.operator-common-0.25.0.jar:0.25.0]
    at io.vertx.core.impl.future.FutureImpl$3.onFailure(FutureImpl.java:128) ~[io.vertx.vertx-core-4.1.2.jar:4.1.2]
    at io.vertx.core.impl.future.FutureBase.lambda$emitFailure$1(FutureBase.java:71) ~[io.vertx.vertx-core-4.1.2.jar:4.1.2]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:164) [io.netty.netty-common-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:469) [io.netty.netty-common-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:500) [io.netty.netty-transport-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:986) [io.netty.netty-common-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) [io.netty.netty-common-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) [io.netty.netty-common-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) [?:?]
```

This is my Kafka Cluster manifest

```
apiVersion: kafka.strimzi.io/v1beta2
kind: Kafka
metadata:
  name: my-cluster
spec:
  kafka:
    version: 2.8.0
    replicas: 1
    listeners:
      - name: plain
        port: 9092
        type: internal
        tls: false
        authentication:
          type: scram-sha-512
      - name: external
        port: 9094
        type: ingress
        tls: true
        authentication:
          type: scram-sha-512
        configuration:
          bootstrap:
            host: localb.kafka.xxx.com
          brokers:
          - broker: 0
            host: local.kafka.xxx.com
```

and this is my ingress controller service

```
NAME                       TYPE           CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP      PORT(S)                      AGE   SELECTOR
ingress-nginx-controller   LoadBalancer   10.111.221.8   10.104.187.226   80:30856/TCP,443:31698/TCP   14h   app.kubernetes.io/component=controller,app.kubernetes.io/instance=ingress-nginx,app.kubernetes.io/name=ingress-nginx
```

Could you please help me out, how did you deloy Kafka with Strimzi on prem?

Comment: It looks like this is the key point: `Exceeded timeout of 300000ms while waiting for Ingress resource my-cluster-kafka-bootstrap in namespace default to be addressable`. Is there any `Ingress` called `my-cluster-kafka-bootstrap` in the `default` `namespace` ? It looks like it is expected to exist. What does `kubectl get ingress -n default my-cluster-kafka-bootstrap` return ?

Answer (score 2):

The error from Strimzi means that the `Ingress` resources are missing the `.status` section. When the Nginx Ingress controller registers them, it normally sets the status to something like this:

```yaml
  status:
    loadBalancer:
      ingress:
      - ip: 192.168.1.245
```

where the IP address is the Ingress IP address (so in your case it would be `10.104.187.226`). Strimzi is waiting for this and without it will not see the Ingresses as *ready*.

But that did not happened in our case. From my experience, that mostly means that the Ingress controller had not found the Ingress instances. They might be missing the right *class* name in the Ingres `.spec` or in the annotation, they might be in a namespace the Ingress controller is not watching for etc. Checking the log of the Ingress controller might help.

Comment: thank you @Jakub! you were completly right! thy have closed my question and i cannot vote for your answer but every single word is correct; it was the ingress class missing...